# XeLaTeX plus (‘+’) sign undefined

Tags: xetex, fontspec, texshop

I'm using XeLaTeX with specified fonts CMU and UbuntuMono

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Extension = .ttf, Path = ./../fonts/, UprightFont = *rm, ItalicFont = *it]{cmun}
\setmathfont[Extension = .ttf, Path = ./../fonts/]{cmunit}
\setmonofont[Extension = .ttf, Path = ./../fonts/, UprightFont = *-Roman, ItalicFont = *-Italic]{UbuntuMono}
```

However, anytime I'm trying to use any simple math symbol just like plus or equal sign in math mode, it throws error. For example:

```
./report.tex:190 Undefined control sequence.
<argument> (2+
              1)\cdot (2\text {+}1)
l.190 \end{longtabu}
```

For line 127

```
\(\frac{1}{(2+1)\cdot(2\text{+}1)}\text{=}0{,}11\)
```

With ‘+’ sign specified as ‘\text{+}’ I getting no trouble except for innormal binary operator spacing.

I have no idea how can I fix it

Comment: inside a tabular (of any kind)  I don't see the reason to use math in `\[\]`. Use `\(\)` instead. `\[\]` would possibly work in a miniopage... but I can not see it (since you didn't provided a MWE :https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Why would you set the math font to `cmunit`, which isn't a math font to begin with? The standard font used by `unicode-math` is Latin Modern Math, which blends nicely with CMUnicode.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are using a math environment of the type `\[ ... \]` inside a tabular (`longtabu`) environment.

Possibly you are not using it inside a `minipage` or somewhere that could be acceptable.

For example check this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \(F(x)+3\) & %does work
    %\[g(x)+9\] Doesn't work
    \begin{minipage}[b]{4cm}
\[g(x)+9\] % Does work but... not reason for it
    \end{minipage}
    \\
    z & 6
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Reason:
The `\[\]` environment "says" to the compiler to place the math their own line, centered etc. But inside the tabular, if theri is not a minipage or something similar... there is no line to add... no center of line etc...

Comment: I've replaced it with `\(\frac{1}{(2+1)\cdot(2+1)}=0{,}11\)` but still having same problem. I also tryed to use XITS Math font but getting same result for operators like ‘+’ and ‘=’. `\cdot`/`\times` works correctly.

Comment: Please read the link of the comment on your answer and provide a MWE. Nobody can help you otherwise. I just found an obvious mistake. This was the only I (or anyone) could do . You can Edit your post providing a MWE that demonstrates the problem and I am sure you will be helped in minutes...